# How to get value from dictionary in lwc

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html

I am attempting to dynamically pull an array via a dictionary in lwc. I am new to lwc and javascript and am having trouble getting the objects to transfer data between components.

My code is as follows:

**data js**

```
export const sectionsAndFields = {
    'Approval': [{'value':1},{'value':2},{'value':3}],
    'list_2': [{'value':4},{'value':5},{'value':6}]
};
```

**reader js**

```
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";
import { sectionsAndFields } from "c/data";

export default class FinancialPlanFieldFinderLayout extends LightningElement {
  @api displaymarker;
  sectionsAndFields = sectionsAndFields;
  keyer = sectionsAndFields[this.displaymarker];

  @api
  get displayMarkerGetSet() {
    return this._displaymarker;
  }
  set displayMarkerGetSet(value) {
    this.setAttribute("displaymarker", value);
    this._displaymarker = value;
  }
```

**reader html**

```
<template>
  <lightning-card title={displaymarker}>
      <div>displaymarker: {displaymarker}</div>
      <div>keyer: {keyer}</div>
      <div>sectionsAndFields: {sectionsAndFields}</div>
      <div>sectionsAndFields data: {sectionsAndFields.data}</div>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Of the values rendered in the reader html, I get the following:

- {displaymarker} renders `Approval` (the default value from a parent
  component)
- {keyer} renders nothing
- {sectionsAndFields} renders `[object Object]`
- {sectionsAndFields.data} renders nothing

What I expected to happen was as follows:

- {keyer} renders `[{'value':1},{'value':2},{'value':3}]` (from data.js)
- {sectionsAndFields} renders `[object Object]`
- {sectionsAndFields.data} renders `[{'value':1},{'value':2},{'value':3}]` (from data.js)

Can someone help me understand why {keyer} and {sectionsAndFields.data} are returning null, and how to correct this so as to get the dictionary value from the input key?

Comment: `displayMarkerGetSet` appears to never be called. Also, you're copying to `_displaymarker`, which is never defined. `keyer` is rightfully null, since `sectionsAndFields[null]` is null. `sectionAndFields.data` is not defined, either. Overall, there's a ton of mistakes here. What's your actual objective?

Comment: @sfdcfox `displaymarker` is fed in through the parent component. My goal is to dynamically pull an array from data.js, using `displaymarker` as the key (If `displaymarker` changes, the array changes, etc.) I am very new to lwc and javascript so please forgive my errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things,

1) There is no `data` attribute in data.js `sectionsAndFields` . The two attribute it has is `Approval` and `list_2`. So when you try to access `data` in markup as

`<div>sectionsAndFields data: {sectionsAndFields.data}</div>`
would return nothing.

fix: Use `Approval` or `list_2` as key.

```
<div>sectionsAndFields data: {sectionsAndFields.Approval}</div>
```

2) `keyer` should be getter as its dependent on input, had it been hardcoded values, You can just use as it like

`keyer =  sectionsAndFields['Approval']` and it would work. But our case is to use dynamic values, hence getter seems better option.

```
get keyer(){
      return this.sectionsAndFields[this.displaymarker];
    }
```

Playground Link : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/EyWz26Ub/7/edit